# HttpUrlConnection Reading an Input Stream Returns "-1"

Tags: java, android, pdf, httpurlconnection

I am sending a post request to a server. After a successful request, the response sends pdf data to the client for download. I am trying to generate the pdf file with the response and save it to the Android device. I have successfully created the request, the empty pdf file, and I have even received a successful response. Although, when I call .getInputStream() it returns a "**-1**". As a result, the while loop exits with the error *java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4096; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1*.

I understand why I am receiving this error, but I do not know how to get the data response.

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.d("LOGOUT", "CREATING REQUEST");

        boolean successful = false;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        URL downloadURL = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        PrintWriter out= null;
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        File file = null;
        int totalsize;

        try {

            downloadURL = new URL("http://exampleurl.com");

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) downloadURL.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            String data = "param=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[0], "UTF-8") + "&submit=" + URLEncoder.encode("Submit", "UTF-8");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + data.length());

            String sdCard = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
            file = new File(sdCard + File.separator + "test.pdf");
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            out.write(data);
            out.close();

            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

            int read;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) ; {

                Log.d("LOGOUT", "BUFFER: " + read);
                // **The LOGOUT message reads "BUFFER: -1" within Logcat**
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            successful = true;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.d("LOGOUT", "ERROR: " + e);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.d("LOGOUT", "ERROR: " + e);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("LOGOUT", "ERROR: " + e);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("LOGOUT", "ERROR: " + e);

        } finally {

            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    Log.d("LOGOUT", "CLOSING INPUTSTREAM");
                    inputStream.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("LOGOUT", "ERROR: " + e);
                }

                if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        fileOutputStream.close();
                        Log.d("LOGOUT", "CLOSING FILEOUTPUTSTREAM");

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d("LOGOUT", "ERROR: " + e);

                    }
                }

            }
            if (connection != null) {
                Log.d("LOGOUT", "CLOSING CONNECTION");
                connection.disconnect();

            }

        }

        return successful;
    }
```

I am receiving the correct response headers. I have listed them below...

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=examplefilename.pdf
Content-Type:application/pdf
Date:Wed, 21 Oct 2015 13:59:45 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.22
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:User-Agent
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.29
```

I know for a fact I am sending/receiving a successful request/response, but I am unable to download the pdf data. Finally, I do not have control over the server. I am interacting with a third party application.

What am I doing wrong to accomplish the task? If not that, does anyone have any idea on where I could look to solve the problem? Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: `when I call .getInputStream() it returns a "-1". `. Nonsense. It will return a valid InputStream or null if the stream is not available.

Comment: `I am trying to generate the pdf file with the response`. What are you trying to do? If the server sends you pdf data then the only thing you have to do is save that data to file. You don't have to generate anything as the server already generated the pdf.

Comment: @greenapps Oops, when I call .read() against the input stream, it returns a -1. My terminology was off. My bad. - You are correct. I am trying to save the data to a file.

Comment: Place the three lines, starting with `String sdCard = En...` behind `out.close();`. After that remove `out.close():`.

Comment: How do you read those headers?

Comment: Can you post screenshot of the debug result (when you got -1), and if you used Postman to test, post its screenshot for more info.